# Paypal IPN - hidden "return" field receives information too

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working with some Paypal IPN project and I found something that started worrying me.

The following fields are set in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.com/succes.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com/ipn_handler.php" />
```

Anyway, when an user pays, he will be returned to the success.php page and wont have anything to do with the ipn_handler.php, but my success.php url (in the addreess bar) looks like this after returning from Paypal:

```
http://mysite.com/success.php?transaction_subject=57&txn_type=web_accept&payment_date=07%3A53%3A24+Oct+03%2C+2012+PDT&last_name=SOMETHING&residence_country=US&pending_reason=multi_currency&item_name=SOMETHING&payment_gross=&mc_currency=EUR&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&payment_type=instant&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&payer_status=verified&verify_sign=Adm5TcLO5.Dgm0ttCdwtx43iz69qAOB8yELzqmpoKwztT.v5nX7naEIQ&txn_id=77L26596YM827223E&payer_email=dugagj_1346872586_per%40gmail.com&tax=0.00&test_ipn=1&first_name=SOMETHING&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&quantity=0&payer_id=4D9U3R4S4D7CC&receiver_id=Y2CCK4NAA75Q2&item_number=&payment_status=Pending&mc_gross=25.00&custom=57&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.7&merchant_return_link=Return+to+Sandbox&auth=AqXhaNS8jZidb-pkJqUa3t2qAy-SPrpCt12155Ku703imQ3302J0cHyBD36AdiSVrY6hMc3JN6gwQo9gmRlxQjA
```

I don't like my address bar showing all this information. Is this dangerous? Am I doing something wrong when setting up the HTML?

Please help.

P.S: The url above was created via Paypal Sandbox, therefore you should not worry as it doesn't include anything from real payments.

Comment: Do you have payment data transfer (PDT) enabled?

Comment: I don't know, I never tried my script with live payments yet, I am working with the Sandbox only and the default sandbox account `seller@paypalsandbox.com` to try stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Check your rm variable when submitting your form to paypal.

You may have set the rm variable to 0, 1 or not set at all (default is 0). If you submit this variable with value 2 then all info will come to your success.php page with POST.

So in your form set the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
```

See the documentation for the `rm` variable [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B)

You can read more [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/website-payments-standard/getting-payment-data-paypal-auto-return-pdt-ipn-demystified)

Comment: Also ensure you've got 'Auto Return' and 'Payment Data Transfer' switched off.